# How do I reformat these dates to mm/dd/yyyy format in Excel?

Tags: excel, date, format

I have a list of dates like "2022 25th Jan" and "2022 3rd Jun" that I want to display in Excel as "1/25/2022" and "6/3/2022". How do I get Excel to reformat this column for me?

Comment: You have text-that-look-like-dates. They need converted to dates (numbers). Lots of resources on the Internet to get you started.

Comment: Like BigBen mentioned, it appears to be a text string. The best way to fix is to change the source code that's sending you the data to format as a proper date prior to you receiving it. Otherwise, you'll need to "manually" change the data using some find/replace options or use formulas to extract the right elements into another cell.

Comment: `=--REPLACE(MID(A1,6,LEN(A1))&" "&LEFT(A1,4),3,2,"")`

Comment: You may try this, it works `=LET(a,REDUCE(A1,{"st","nd","rd","th"},LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,""))),
DATE(LEFT(a,4),MONTH(RIGHT(a,3)&1),MID(a,6,2)))` and since dates are stored as numbers in excel it will return a number you need to format it accordingly as mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @SarahRussell since it has worked, I should post it in `Answer` so that some one facing same issue in future may find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Since OP has mentioned it has worked in comments above, hence posting it as an Answer, so that someone facing the same issue in future may find it useful,***

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=LET(a,REDUCE(A1,{"st","nd","rd","th"},LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,b,""))),
DATE(LEFT(a,4),MONTH(RIGHT(a,3)&1),MID(a,6,2)))
```

---

One more alternative approach using `TEXTJOIN()`

[image: Formula_Solution]

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=--TEXTJOIN("/",,LEFT(A1,4),MONTH(RIGHT(A1,3)&1),MAX(IFERROR(MID(A1,6,{2,1})+0,0)))
```

---

**Note:** *Since dates are stored as sequential serial numbers in Excel hence the returned value will be a serial number, therefore you need to format the date as* `mm/dd/yyyy` *as well. Formula provided applicable to `MS365` users only.*

---

Answer (score 2):

Using REPLACE and other string parsers:

```
=LET(r,A1,
    dm,MID(r,6,LEN(r)),
    --REPLACE(dm&" "&LEFT(r,4),IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(dm,2,1)),3,2),2,""))
```

[image]

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya you are correct, I assumed that the day would always be two digits.